# Nuxt3 Server Event does not wait for node mailer

Tags: nuxt3

I am trying to do a simple contact form in my nuxt3 website. Everything works fine but I can not make the server event wait for the email to be sent in order to return a result

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

  const mailOptions = {
    from: `myemail`,
    to: ['myemail'],
    bcc: ['myemail']
  };

  const body = await readBody(event)

  const email = EmailValidator.validate(body.email);

  if(!email) {
    throw createError({
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Please input a valid email',
    })
  }

  if(body.name.length < 4) {
    throw createError({
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Please input a valid name',
    })
  }

  if(body.message.length < 16) {
    throw createError({
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Please input a valid message',
    })
  }

  mailOptions.subject = 'XX - Web Enquiry'
  mailOptions.html =   `
    <h5>We have received a enquiry through XX website:</h5>
    <p>Name: ${body.name}</p>
    <p>Email: ${body.email}</p>
    <p>Message: ${body.message}</p>
  `;
  
  const send = await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if(!err) {
      return {
        success: true,
        e: ''
      }
    }
    return {
      success: false,
      e: 'Something went wrong'
    }
  })

  if(send) {
    return send
  }

  return {}
})
```

This code send the email but it automatically return an empty object (last line)... I tried returning `setResponseStatus(event, 202)` as the guide suggest but it gives me an error too... it just work if I put the final return otherwise just fail

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well in case someone bump into this issue in the future...

The reason is that `await` on node-mailer `sendEmail` does not actually return a promise if you provide a callback function :)

> If callback argument is not set then the method returns a Promise
> object. Nodemailer itself does not use Promises internally but it
> wraps the return into a Promise for convenience.

this should be the correct code according to my question:

```
...
const send = await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
... handle errors
```